# Ising interactions - What are they?

Tags: electromagnetism, ising-model, dipole-moment

The energy function of an Ising model is $\sum_{i\sim j} s_i J_{ij} s_j$. In terms of the graph, $J_{ij}$ can be the edge weight.

What is the physical nature of the interactions $J_{ij}$?

Are they just [magnetic field interactions between dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction)? If so, that means it is just dipoles in a Cartesian space with interactions scaled as the inverse fourth power of distance. Why do we bother defining regular lattices for them? Why not just make assume a local field at each site that is accumulated from all the other dipole moments?

Or are the interactions due to something else like electron cloud interactions between neighbors?

I am sorry if this sounds like an elementary question. I am a non-physicist who found Ising models interesting for their applications in other systems.

Comment: The Ising model has a huge number of different interpretations, usually with no link to magnetism at all, and the interpretation of the coupling constant $J_{ij}$ is different in each case. Note also that, even if you restrict yourself to the magnetic interpretation,  the Ising model was introduced before the proper microscopic origins of magnetism were understood.

Comment: You can actually show it isn't about classical dipole-dipole interaction, but the exchange interaction of the electrostatic force! (Hence written as $J$)